# PHPMyadmin checkboxes displays "Array"

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've searched extensively but can't find an answer… Hope someone can help:

I'm a newbie PHP and MySQL user and have a problem with checkboxes.

I have a simple HTML page which contains checkboxes.
The page is linked up to a MySQL db in PHPmyadmin.

The HTML is:

```
<html><p>User1<input type="checkbox" name="Users[]" id="Users1" value="1"/></p>
<p>User2<input type="checkbox" name="Users[]" id="Users2" value="2"/></p>
<p>User3<input type="checkbox" name="Users[]" id="Users3" value="3"/></p>
<p>User4<input type="checkbox" name="Users[]" id="Users4" value="4"/></p></html>
```

What I want is for the person filling in the form to check 1 or more of the values and then for the checked values to be displayed in PHPmyadmin, so that I can export them.

However, when using this PHP:

```
$values = implode(',', $_POST['Users']);
```

All I get in PHPmyadmin is "Array", and I can't figure out how to get the actual values to be displayed.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: there seems to be nothing wrong with `$values = implode(',', $_POST['Users'])`. What exactly are you trying to display in PHPMyAdmin? The `implode()` always returns a string, never an Array. It seems you are trying to use `echo` to display some array; instead use print_r()

Comment: Try a `var_dump($_POST); exit()` at the top of your script, to see exactly what's being submitted. If the `Users` parameter shows up fine in there, then something else in your code is mangling the values in the $_POST array.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all value checked by looping :

```
$userChecked = $_POST['Users'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($userChecked ); $i++) {
    echo( ($i+1) . ") " . $userChecked [$i] . "<br/>");
}
```

This will display all id. Instead of echo the value you can insert them in your database or do what you want. The values will be loop inside :  $userChecked [$i]

> @Daok: Yes, that displays the values
>   on the results page, but in
>   PHPmyadmin, it still indicates
>   "Array". How do I get it to display
>   the values?

PhpMyAdmin is just a tool to administrate php/mysql. I guess you mean that you have "array" written in your database? If you do want all value inside a field (varchar) than you just have to `implode`:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $_POST['Users']);
//Code here to Insert to you database with ...value($comma_separated)...
```

If you want 1 row for each entry :

```
$userChecked = $_POST['Users'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($userChecked ); $i++) {
   //Insert Sql statement here with value($userChecked [$i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$values = implode(',', (array)$_POST['Users']);
```

or

```
Users=array();
$values = implode(',', $_POST['Users']);
```